# Display records in sequence from a table without relying on the id of the table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a table consists of 3 columns, the number of the records in the table always change after many operations of insertion and deletion over the table, so the auto increment id in the table can't give me an accurate sequence of records fetched. for example at some point I want to fetch a group of records (individually one at a time) according to a condition. The ids of these 10 records will not be in sequence. so how can I say for example the fifth record out of these 10?

```
 select @num:=@num+1 as id, x, y from test where g=true;
```

the query above gives me the group of records I need with sequential key (id) but I don't want to fetch all of them together, I want each one of them individually and in sequence.

Comment: Your question isnt clear.  Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LIMIT` clause to select from a sequence at a particular offset:

```
select id, x, y
  from test
 where g=true
 limit 4, 1;
```

Note that there's no guarantee that the results will be in any consistent sequence unless you use `ORDER BY`. In your case, you can probably order on `id`.

Comment: Perfect! even simpler and without generating a new column. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, you can use a subquery -- also you should initialize the `user defined variable`:

```
select *
from (
    select @num:=@num+1 as id, x, y 
    from test cross join (select @num:=0) t
    where g=true
    order by test.id
) y
where id = 5
```

Also, you would want to include an `order by` in your subquery -- presumably `order by test.id` to guarantee the order of the results.

Comment: Yeeh this is what I meant first, but I think "Limit" makes the solution much simpler.

Comment: @Hussein -- yes, I agree -- `limit` is easier for this particular case.